# Is it good practice to organize class methods into specialized sub-classes?

Tags: java, subclass, reorganize

A class end up exposing all its methods and fields under the same level and get extremely unorganized.

Would it be better to organize it in specialized sub-classes. Below is an example of a messy class.

```
public class MyClass
{
  //[Properties]
  public String value1;
  public String value2;

  //[Methods used by outside world]
  public void job1()
  {
     job1_task1();
     job1_task2();

     utilInternal1();
     utilExternal1();
  }
  public void job2()
  {
     job2_task1();

     utilInternal1();
     utilExternal1();
  }

  //[Methods used locally and always specific to a job method]
  private static void job1_task1() ...
  private static void job1_task2() ...
  private static void job2_task1() ...

  //[Methods used locally and general to jobs methods]
  private static void utilInternal1() ...

  //[Methods that could be added to an external class util]
  public static void utilExternal1() ...
}
```

So far i have organized my code in sub specialized classes such as Props, Jobs, Tasks, Utils.Internal, Utils.Externals.

- Instance class like Jobs and Props. Are exposed via two instance fields. They will use directly instance variable.
- Static class can be directly used such as Tasks and Utils. They will NOT use directly instance variable.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Prop Props = new Prop();
  public Job Jobs = new Job();

  //[Properties]
  private class Prop
  {
     public String value1;
     public String value2;
  }

  //[Methods used by outside world]
  public class Job
  {
      public void job1()
      {
         Tasks.Job1.task1();
         Tasks.Job1.task2();

         Utils.internal.util1();
         Utils.external.util1();
      }
      public void job2()
      {
         Tasks.Job2.task1();

         Utils.internal.util1();
         Utils.external.util1();
      }
  }

//[Tasks for Jobs]
  private static class Tasks
  {
      //[Tasks for job1]
      private static class ForJob1
      {
          private static void task1() ...
          private static void task2() ...
      }
      //[Tasks for job2]
      private static class ForJob2
      {
          private static void task1() ...
      }
  }

  private static class Utils
  {
      //[methods util used locally]
      private static class Internal
      {
          private static void util1() ...
      }
      //[methods util generic that could be added to an external class Util]
      private static class External
      {
          public static void util1() ...
      }
  }
}
```

I made static most of the sub class containing methods that must not use directly class variable, instead they will ask them as parameters.
Tasks are useless to external class and only have meaning locally in our class.

```
private static Task
{
   private static ForJob1
   {
      private static String task1(String value)
      {
          String result = value + ".";

          return result;
      }
   }
}
```

Is it something that is acceptable ?

My concern is also about the memory usage ?

Comment: *My concern is also about the memory usage ?* - why?

Comment: *Is it something that is acceptable ?* Makes the code harder to read, I would say no on that basis.

Comment: I would recommend studying SOLID principles. https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design https://stackify.com/solid-design-principles/

Comment: @ScaryWombat does it increase the size of the object in memory if you have a class that contains multiple sub classes ?

Comment: @DCTID thank you for the link, i am going to read it. Do you see anything wrong doing it that way. I mean organizing piece of code in methods is already helping to organize class and it is recommended. Now organizing methods in sub class is it something that is fine or it really have risks ? maybe memory issues ? Others ?. if it is the case please detail your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @fra in general the way you organize your code is not going to have a practical effect on performance. That said if you have a particularly large program, millions of lines of code or more it is possible.

Comment: @fra But, I believe you are asking more generally. Imho the most important factors in code are readability and testability. I don't personally believe your inner classes support either very well. It is just too much with too many different responsibilities. I have never seen anyone use inner classes like you do professionally. Most devs would put those into separate files. However, if you personally or your team finds that standard helps you write working software faster I would never argue with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DCTID